# After authenticating via POST, I need to do a GET using Ajax

Tags: javascript, ajax, api, xmlhttprequest

I'm attempting to create a dashboard that logs into an API then refreshes certain data elements that is fully automated. I can login and authenticate but after googling unsure how to 'chain' the GET request after the 'POST'

I've tried watching a few youtube tutorials and creating functions, attaching them to buttons and divs but I just can't get the data to display. The first batch of code completes and logs in OK, but then sits there and times out. I tried just adding a second open and making the login synchronous but it failed

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    const xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
    var data = 'username=user&password=password';

    xhr.onreadystatechange = function()
    {
        if (xhr.readyState == "4")
    {
            if (xhr.status == "200")
            {
                console.log(xhr.responseText);
            }

            if (xhr.status = "404")
            {
            console.log("FnF");
            }

        }
    }
    xhr.open('post','https://apiServer:8443/api/login', true)
    xhr.setRequestHeader("Content-Type", "application/x-www-form-urlencoded")
    xhr.setRequestHeader("Accept", "application/xml")
    //xhr.open('get', 'https://apiServer:8443/api/resource/items', true);
    xhr.send();
```

I'm expecting the login to be done behind the scenes and not visible, and just have the GET request show data in a div (I'll try and tidy up the xml response when I get the data working first).

Answer (score 0):

In your code you never use your `data` variable :

```
const xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
var data = 'username=user&password=password';

xhr.onreadystatechange = function()
{
    if (xhr.readyState == "4")
    {
        if (xhr.status == "200")
        {
            console.log(xhr.responseText);
        }

        if (xhr.status = "404")
        {
        console.log("FnF");
        }

    }
}
xhr.open('post','https://apiServer:8443/api/login', true)
xhr.setRequestHeader("Content-Type", "application/x-www-form-urlencoded")
xhr.setRequestHeader("Accept", "application/xml")
//xhr.open('get', 'https://apiServer:8443/api/resource/items', true);
xhr.send(data); // <====== HERE
```